# How to Install LXQt on Lubuntu 18.04 (and replicate the look of newer Lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, themes, icon-themes, lxqt

My laptop doesn't seem to want to work with Lubuntu 19.10, so I'm trying to replicate the look of the new Lubuntu with LXQt and the theme on it.

What are the steps and what should I install to install LXQt and make it look like Lubuntu 19.10?

Comment: `lxqt` was not supported by the Lubuntu team on 18.04 (*except for limited testing*) because it wasn't deemed 'ready'. The main package will be https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lxqt but there have been a lot of changes in LXQt since the packages in 18.04 are now old. I have no experience with what you're after, and Lubuntu Next is now EOL (https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/ https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/04/are-you-ready-for-lubuntu-next-1804.html)

Comment: So the packages for lxqt in 18.04 is not up to date with the ones on the latest lubuntu?

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way to have the theme or look of the lubuntu 19.10 (which uses LXQt and somekind of flat/material design theme). So I thought maybe i should start by installing LXQt on Lubuntu 18.04 and then do the modifications to make it look like Lubuntu 19.10, because my laptop doesnt work with the latest lubuntu versions

Comment: For packages and why they aren't kept up-to-date (or the latest), see https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software.  Specifics, Lubuntu started the move to LXQt (& *Lubuntu Next*) in 15.04 (2015-April release), but it took time for LXQt to mature (it was new, LXDE devs had joined with RazorQt to form the new LXQt) and thus Lubuntu to switch to it. This wasn't deemed ready for 18.04 & pushed to 18.10 so Lubuntu only really supports LXDE for 18.04.  Theme etc is more possible - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Theming